# binding variable value to views or specific section/div of html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A button creates a div element dynamically inside my single page app each time it is clicked. Now I want to bind each new div element with the timestamp it was created.

When buttons in these div element are clicked they should alert the timestamp they were created.

My code is something like this

```
$("#creatediv").click(function() {
    var n = new Date().getTime();
    $("#containerdiv").append("<div id='"+n+"-postfixtext'>"+n+"extrastuff \
        <div id='onemorediv'><button class='showtimestamp'></button></div></div>");
});

$("button.showtimestamp").click(function(){
    alert("the timestamp value is");
});
```

The button nesting level is not specific so I can can not use something like

```
$(this).parent().parent().attr("id").split('-')[0];
```

to get the value of timestamp.

**Question:**

1. How can I bind value of a variable in a to specific element and its children?
   If I want to change the value of that variable in specific element then it should be changed only in that element
2. <strike>Do I need to use a global object which stores the data and pass the index of that data as id of all children within the newly created div?</strike>
3. <strike>Or would it be better to use data binding frameworks like angular.js or backbone? if yes then how it should be done?</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.data()` methods to add metadata to the element as you create it.

```
$("#creatediv").click(function() {
    var n = new Date().getTime();
    var div = $("<div id='"+n+"-postfixtext'></div>");
    div.data('createdTimestamp', n);
    div.append(extrastuff);
    div.append( $("<button>Click for timestamp</button>")
        .data("parentDiv", div)
        .click( function(ev) {
             var parentDiv = $(this).data('parentDiv');
             var createdTimestamp = parentDiv.data('createdTimestamp');
             alert("the timestamp value is" + createdTimestamp);
        })
    );
});
```

Note that in my example, you could technically skip all the setting and looking up of data using the `.data()` calls, and instead just reference the `n` variable directly in the `.click()` event handler. If you do it that way, it would be an example of a Javascript closure. But the example as I've written it is more to demonstrate the use of `.data()`.

**UPDATE**

Here is the example above, edit to use closures, instead of the `.data()` methods from jQuery:

```
$("#creatediv").click(function() {
    var n = new Date().getTime();
    var div = $("<div id='"+n+"-postfixtext'></div>");
    div.append(extrastuff);
    div.append( $("<button>Click for timestamp</button>")
        .click( function(ev) {
             alert("the timestamp value is" + n);
        })
    );
});
```

You can reference the `n` variable directly from your `.click()` event handler, because `n` is still in scope inside the event handler. This way doesn't use the `.data()` methods of jQuery at all.

Comment: the content of newly created div is dynamic so I can't bind the button with click even the button with data directly so I have to bind the data to all children using $('#'+n+"-postfixtext *").data("createdTimestamp",n); is this a good method to do so?

Comment: I think that would depend on how many elements are getting data bound to them. Can you access the button through a combination of selectors, like, `$('#'+n+'-postfixtext .showtimestamp')`? Here I'm assuming `showtimestamp` is a class on the button you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

You can you used jQuery data function for save time stamp and attach timestamp with each element
and for binding click event used jQuery live event

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: From the page you linked : As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: so you are suggesting I can set a tstamp variable  jQuery.data('#'+n+'-postfixtext *',"tstamp",n );                    and then get the data from any child element using $(this).data("tstamp")?